# create vectors for each ordered column df r

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
red<- c(21,4,6,4)
blue<- c(45,65,2,4)
black<- c(7,34,1,60)
df<- data.frame(red, blue, black)
row.names(df)<- c('a','b','c','d')
```

I would like to order each column (decreasing = TRUE) of the df and create a vector of this ordered column (with each vector being called the column name)
eg:

```
red = 21,6,4,4
blue = 65,45,4,2
black = 60,34,7,1
```

I have tried to do this for the first column:

```
z<-numeric(0)
for (i in 1)){

j<-order(df[,i], decreasing = TRUE)
n<-names(df)[i]
z<-paste(n,k)}
```

But this is wrong as firstly it prints the name each time (I only want to paste the name once) and it gives me the index and I want the row names)

As you can tell I'm a beginner

Comment: How do I 'accept' an answer? I give an 'upvote' for every answer that I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `sort`  on individual columns with `lapply` and assign the output `list` back to the original dataset

```
df[] <- lapply(df, sort, decreasing = TRUE)
```

If we need the row.names as well (not clear based on the expected output - which is a `vector`)

```
lst1 <- lapply(names(df), function(nm) {
        dat <- df[nm]
       dat[order(dat[[1]], decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
 })

lst1[[1]]
#  red
#a  21
#c   6
#b   4
#d   4

lst1[[2]]
#  blue
#b   65
#a   45
#d    4
#c    2
```

If the intention is to create multiple objects (not recommended)

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(lst1, row.names), names(df)), .GlobalEnv)
red
#[1] "a" "c" "b" "d"
blue
#[1] "b" "a" "d" "c"
black
#[1] "d" "b" "a" "c"
```

Or it could be simplified

```
list2env(lapply(df, function(x)
        row.names(df)[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)]), .GlobalEnv)
```

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
rownames_to_column(df, 'rn') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% 
  arrange(name, desc(value)) %>%
  {split(.$rn, .$name)} %>% 
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or if the values needs to be output of each of the new objectss

```
list2env(lapply(df, sort, decreasing = TRUE), .GlobalEnv)
red
#[1] 21  6  4  4
blue
#[1] 65 45  4  2
black
#[1] 60 34  7  1
```

---

Or using the `for` loop with `assign`

```
for(nm in names(df)) assign(nm, sort(df[[nm]], decreasing = TRUE))
```

---

In `dplyr`, it can be done with

```
df %>%
   mutate_all(sort, decreasing = TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear as the rownames are important. e.g. df[] <- lapply(df, sort, decreasing = TRUE) doesn't work for my as in the original table b, blue is 65, now a, blue is 65. This is why I though I needed to create vectors for each column

Comment: @zoe Your expected in the post is `red = 21,6,4,4`, this is what it gives.  Please check the `list2env(lapply(df, sort, decreasing = TRUE), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @zoe Anyway,  I don't want to spend more time on this bcz I didn't get the reply to the comment below your post

Comment: In the orginal df a = 21 for red, 45 for blue and 7 for black. b = 4 for red, 65 for blue and 34 for black. I want to preserve the relationship between row name and column name . I want to loop over each column and create a vector of the ordered row names. e.g. red = a,c,b,d, blue = b,a,d,c.